# How to evaluate validity about Causal Discovery?

Tags: causality, bayesian-network, dag, causal-diagram

When I was trying to do structural learning for causal inference, I perplex for too many causal discovery algorithms(PC, FCI, GES, NOTEARS and more...)

There are many structural learning algorithm for causal discovery.
For example, if you get two different structures from many algorithms, which one is best? which one is similar with real causal relation?
And, if you get only one structures from many algorithms, how to know it is similar with real causal relation?

Comment: What happens if you manipulate?

Answer (score 5):

Often, you don't even get a complete structure, with constraint-based methods like PC or FCI, it is usually only a Markov Equivalence Class (MEC), which is a set of several possible structures (causal graphs).

And since those algorithms compute the MEC from noisy data, they can come up with different results. E.g., if they are based on conditional independence tests, those are quite difficult to get right, they prefer larger amounts of data, and the inferred independence relations often contradict each other.

I don't think that one can say that one of those algorithms is generally better than the others, the difference is more in what they are capable of. E.g. FCI can deal with latent confounders while PC cannot.

If it makes sense to use [score-based methods](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1792/paper7.pdf), you have at least the score to guide you with your decision.

Note that there are *a lot* more possible approaches, like constraint-based, score-based, inequality-based, additive noise model based, ... And if you are willing to apply several of those, you might want to go for a majority vote, or some other, more sophisticated, ensemble method.

Once you have lowered the number of candidates, there is also the possibility of applying some model selection technique, e.g. the one described in [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v138/biza20a/biza20a.pdf).

In general, it is often impossible to obtain the correct causal structure just from observed data. And one would require [intervention](https://www.cmu.edu/dietrich/philosophy/docs/scheines/PSA2006.pdf) data to properly check the results.

Answer (score 0):

### Make sure the assumptions underlying the algorithms suit your problem

There is no point in comparing these algorithms in a vacuum, as they rely on very different assumptions. For example, many independence tests used for PC and FCI are linear, FCI allows for unobserved confounders while PC does not, GES and NOTEARS require a score function which typically relies on distributional assumptions, and NOTEARS' optimization routine additionally assumes convexity. So perhaps **the primary question to ask yourself** is:

**What assumptions am I willing to make about my data generating process, and which methods can I use for causal discovery based on these assumptions?**

This will allow you to select a subset of methods which you can then go on to compare with respect to the goal of your particular task.